# iOS - Setting UISwitch on/off state on a Modal View Controller

Tags: ios, boolean, modalviewcontroller, uiswitch

I'm having problems setting the state of a UISwitch from a BOOL. This is probably simple, so if anybody could help I'd really appreciate it. Here is my code which doesn't work, but it might make it more clear.

```
 RoutingController *routingController = [[RoutingController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RoutingController" bundle:nil];

routingController.routingDelegate = self;

if (audioController->oscOneLFObool == YES) {
    routingController.oscOneLFOOneSwitch.on = YES;
} else {
    routingController.oscOneLFOOneSwitch.on = NO;
}


routingController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentModalViewController:routingController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Why are your trying to change the bool status? Do you just want something that shows if something is on or not?

Comment: Are you getting any compiler warnings? Do you update/change the switch status in `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` of your RoutingController? Does `NSLog(@"%@", routingController. oscOneLFOOneSwitch);` indicate that you are talking to the right instance? Last but not least, your case-descision does not make sense, replace it by `routingController.oscOneLFOOneSwitch.on = audioController->oscOneLFObool`;

Comment: One more thing, are you positive that audioController is a non-objective C pointer (struct, C++ object,...) ?

Comment: You should be using `if (audioController->oscOneLFObool) {` instead of `if (audioController->oscOneLFObool == YES) {'.  If it is a value other than 1 (which is set by some methods) then your method won't work even though it will evaluate as true using the second method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RoutingController's view not load,so oscOneLFOOneSwitch is nil.

view load in [self presentModalViewController:routingController animated:YES]